# Google Map inconsistent background image overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have created an image and laid it over google maps. Has anyone got experience replacing the stock world map and had it jitter like crazy?

You can see the example here:
http://doopsdesigns.co.uk/code-snips/custom-map.html
http://doopsdesigns.co.uk/code-snips/custom-map.txt

The image is not there on load, if you move the world map around for a minute it will jump into view, I require this to be visible permanently and on load.

As far as I am aware my code is correct and cannot figure out why the image doesn't stay visible.

My code has sprung from here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Very niche error so thought to create a question.

Thanks code-heads, Jason.

Comment: This might be browser-specific as I don't see any problems when I look at the site and scroll around.

Comment: May I ask what browser you are using? Also you did see the overlaying image? It doesnt act as predicted on both chrome and safari.. :/

Comment: I have a feeling you didnt see the image at all too (it is blue and spotty - not at all like google maps). @i alarmed alien

Comment: I don't think I did. This was Safari.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @i alarmed alien. I have updated the code - If you load the example web page again and literally allow 2 minutes to load the image, move around, scroll around the globe a bit. You should see my overlaying image pop up but then disappear regularly.

link to example... http://doopsdesigns.co.uk/code-snips/example-of-break.png